# Visual Studio does not start build output

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild, visual-studio-extensions, vsx, mpf

I work on a custom project system that is based on `MPF`. For the build I have defined a custom target file which defines the minimum set of required targets like `Build`, `Clean` and `Rebuild` so that the project integrates nicely with the Visual Studio IDE; for instance I can trigger a build for a loaded project using <kbd>F6</kbd> shortcut key, whereby the shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd> should also run the application if the build was successful. But, nope... the build output signals success, but Visual Studio does not try to start the application? I´d like to know what´s missing...

My custom project file does not import `Microsoft.Common.targets`, since it´s not a managed lanugage and most stuff provided by the common build target just do not apply to my project system (also I would like to keep the MSBuild integration as slim as possible).

I read the documentation at: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms171468(v=vs.110).aspx; in the Debugging-section the following MSBuild properties are mentioned: `OutputPath`, `AssemblyName` and `OutputType`; my custom `Build` target sets all these properties, so I assumed that Visual Studio knows everything which is required to run my application (of course, even if my language service does not support debugging yet).

The `Build` target definition looks like this...

```
<Target Name="Build" 
        DependsOnTargets="PrepareBuildProperties" 
        Returns="$(TargetPath)">
</Target>
```

I had a look at the `Microsoft.Common.targets` file and found a `Run` target as well. The comment says...

> Run the final build output if it is a .EXE

and it´s basically doing this (this is a shortened version of the original target definition)...

```
<Target Name="Run"
        DependsOnTargets="$(RunDependsOn)">
    <Exec Command="$(TargetPath) $(StartArguments)" 
          WorkingDirectory="$(OutDir)" />
</Target>
```

Should Visual Studio call this target, if I choose the `Start without debugging` command from the `Debug` menu, or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, this statement:

> My custom project file does not import Microsoft.Common.targets, since
>   it´s not a managed lanugage

does not make much sense since any language can use MSBuild .Targets files, not just managed languages. For example, building VC++ projects heavily depends on such files. Now back to the problem.

> the build output signals success, but Visual Studio does not try to
>   start the application? I´d like to know what´s missing

Modern versions of Visual Studio has nothing to do with building projects or running output files. MSBuild manages the whole process. You'll have to specify somewhere that you need some file to be executed after the project gets built.

You can use the [AfterBuild target](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms366724%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to specify a task to be performed after the build is done. This tag goes inside the Project tag of the project file. You can also specify conditions so that the task is only executed when they are satisfied.

Another way is to use custom build steps as discussed in [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd293663.aspx). This method is little more flexible.

There is a third way, but probably the least preferred. You can use post build events. To define a post build event, add this under the Project tag:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEvent> task command goes here </PostBuildEvent>
</PropertyGroup>
```

The problem with this is that it will appear in the Build Events tab of the project properties and so the user can see it and potentially change it. Post build events are designed to be used by the user not the IDE.

The `Exec` tag you mentioned represents a built-in task indicating that the contents of the tag should be interpreted as a command line that should be executed. The three techniques discussed above are all abstractions on top of the `Exec` task. This task runs when you click `Start without debugging`.

Comment: First of all, thanks for the effort you put into your answer... but it doesn´t really help actually. I don´t have a problem with understanding how `MSBuild` works and how I can extend it. Indeed, my language service extension is an unmanaged language like C or C++; the project system is of course based on MSBuild. I have created a custom target file, which invokes a commandline compiler using `Exec` - and so far the build just works fine...

Comment: @Matze I've mentioned three methods to run the output of the project, which is exactly what you asked for. Have you tried any of them and it did not work? Also since you like to keep the MSBuild integration as slim as possible, creating a custom targets file does not serve this purpose. All the methods I mentioned don't need a targets file, they are based only on the project file which reduces MSBuild integration.

Comment: All three methods do not apply to that particular problem. The reason why I have a separate targets file is because the project file itself only declares WHAT needs to be build; target files instead define HOW a project is build. So, I just separate concerns; like Microsoft does with their targets. As I explained, my custom targets file defines targets like `Clean`, `Build`, `Rebuild` and so on; Visual Studio finds and calls them as expected. The only thing I don´t get to work is the `Run` command; or at least I don´t know what target is expected by Visual Studio...